# Read lines based on their length

Tags: ruby, string, file, string-length

I was wondering of more efficient way to only read the strings of a file based on a certain length.  I know this is a naive approach:

```
len = 3
d = Array.new
t = File.open('d.txt').read
t.each_line do |x|
    #+2 accounting for \n\r
    if x.length == (len + 2)
        d.push(x)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has a number of problems:

```
len = 3
d = Array.new
t = File.open('d.txt').read
t.each_line do |x|
    #+2 accounting for \n\r
    if x.length == (len + 2)
        d.push(x)
    end
end
```

First, the entire file is read into memory because of `File.open('d.txt').read`, then split into lines using `each_line`, and finally lines that are the desired length are captured. If the file consisted of 1,000,000 lines and only one was three characters long, there'd be a lot of wasted memory and CPU time.

Instead, write it like this:

```
len = 3
d = []
File.foreach('d.txt') do |x|
  d << x if (x.chomp.length == len)
end
```

`foreach` reads each line, maintaining the line-breaks. `chomp` removes the line break so you can compare the actual line, without line-ends thanks to `chomp`, to `len`. Then, if the length matches, the line gets appended to the array. At no time is the entire file in memory, unless every line is the desired length. This saves memory, and will run extremely fast, maybe even faster than the original that used `read` to slurp the entire file, because that process can take a while if the file is sufficiently big.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the same as your code.

```
d = File.open("d.txt").lines.select{|l| l.chomp.length == len}
```